# send event from asp.net to google calender in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api

I want to send events to my google calendar account from asp.net application

Answer (score 0):

[look at the API](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/)

[Like Murph said in the comment, link to the guide for .Net API](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html)

Comment: i already done with api,added all google.gdata.calender dll then too its not working plz send me whole code

Comment: Which has a specific section for .NET: http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html

Comment: @priti, I never played with google API, I wont spent a few hours to learn something that I'm not to use again.

Comment: @priti we can answer specific questions but there is already sample code in the API docs and we're not going to be able to add anything to that without some more depth to the question

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Google API Calendar
http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/calendar/

http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#CreatingSingle
Create single-occurance event

```
EventEntry entry = new EventEntry();

// Set the title and content of the entry.
entry.Title.Text = "Tennis with Beth";
entry.Content.Content = "Meet for a quick lesson.";

// Set a location for the event.
Where eventLocation = new Where();
eventLocation.ValueString = "South Tennis Courts";
entry.Locations.Add(eventLocation);

When eventTime = new When(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(2));
entry.Times.Add(eventTime);

Uri postUri = new Uri("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full");

// Send the request and receive the response:
AtomEntry insertedEntry = service.Insert(postUri, entry);
```